# Classical Round Table algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Coins with different value are spread in circle around a round table . We can choose any coin such that for any two adjacent pair of coins , atleast one must be selected (both maybe selected too) . In such condition we have to find minimum possible value of coins selected .

I have to respect time complexity so instead of using naive recursive bruteforce , i tried doing it using dynamic programming . But i get Wrong Answer - my algorithm is incorrect .

If someone could suggest an algorithm to do it dynamically , i could code myself in c++ . Also maximum number of coins is 10^6 , so i think O(n) solution exists .

EDIT : Okay , i also add an example .
If coins value around table is 1,2,1,2,2 (in circle) , then minimum value of coin would be 4 by selecting 1st,3rd & 4th(or 5th) .

Comment: Please describe the dynamic-programming approach you got wrong answers with. Have you found a minimized problem instance that it gives you a wrong answer for?

Comment: (Also, is this a contest problem of some sort? Is sounds highly synthetic, particularly the presence of an explicit upper bound on problem sizes).

Comment: There is no question here, or evidence of research, or description of attempts. The problem statement is vague and could use an example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm , yeah it is related to contest problem , but i have simplified and generalized it .
My approach was to break it into sub problems - start with min. value attained by nth coin (obviously its value of nth coin itslef) , then min. possible value attained by selecting (n-1)th coin and so on , also stored results for later use . Answer i thought was min. of first or sencond coin since these are two possible openings , but this conflicted property that atleast one must be selected of two and so gives me Wrong Answer .

Comment: @A.Webb , i have added my research effort and description of attempts in above comment and edited question with an example .

Comment: @user1795954: And how exactly does your dynamic-programming attempt fail to give the wrong answer in the 1,2,1,2,2 case? Have you constructed a test run of it on paper? Can you use insights from that test run to improve the algorithm?

Comment: @HenningMakholm , yeah i did test it on paper . For sample input my algo works fine , but produces wrong answer when n=6 and value of coins is 1,2,3,4,5,6 . My code produces answer 12 which is certainly wrong , we could choose 1,3,5 with resultant as 9 . Here's my code if you wish to see http://pastebin.com/meXNCQ3H .

Answer (score 1):

I think the following algorithm will get you the best solution. I have not gone through your code (sorry):

We will select a random point in the circle to start. Say it's 1. We will look at what happens if it would be selected.

So we select 1. Move up in the circle and you get the choice of selecting 2 or not. This can be shown in a tree where the top branch represents selecting the coin and the lower one not selecting the coin. The numbers represent the total sum of the selected coins.

```
   3 = 1 and 2 both selected
  /
1
  \
   1 = 1 selected, 2 not
```

Now we continue in the circle and get the choice of selecting 3 or not. This gives a tree like

```
         6 = 1, 2 and 3 selected
       /
     3
    /  \
   /     3= 1 and 2 selected, 3 not
  /
1
  \
   \     4 = 1 and 3 selected, 2 not 
    \  /
     1 
      \
        1 = 1 selected, 2 and 3 not
```

Now in that tree, we can prune! Given your problem statement, you have to keep track of which coins are taken to make sure every coin is 'covered'. Say the last 2 coins were not selected. Then you know the the next has to be selected in order not to violate your constraints. More importantly, the possibilities in the rest of your algorithm only depend on the choice of the last 2 coins.

Now look at all branches that have selected the last coin (3). You only need to keep the one with the lowest weight. Both those branches are free to choose what they want in the rest of the algorithm. In this case, we can safely remove the top branch. We then have 3 possible paths left.

Now take a look at what happens if we enumerate the choices for coin 4

```
     3      7= 1, 2 and 4 selected, 3 not
    /  \   /
   /     3
  /       \
           3 =  1 and 2 selected, 3 and 4 not 
1          8 = 1, 3 and 4 selected, 2 not 
  \       /
   \     4 
    \  /  \
     1     4 = 1 and 3 selected, 2 and 4 not 
           5 = 1 and 4 selected, 2 and 3 not
      \  /
        1 
         \
           1 = only 1 selected
```

Now you have 6 choices. However, the lowest branch (only 1 is selected) is invalid because 3 is not adjacent to anything. You can prune that to have 5 branches left. Of those 5 there are 3 that selected 4 (=the last coin so far) and we can do the same thing as before: only keep the cheapest branch. This reduces the number of branches to 3 again.

You can keep doing this for your whole circle until you reach the start again. Then you should have 3 paths of which you can choose the cheapest. This gives you the best solution if you start of by selecting coin 1.

Now we have the best solution for when 1 is selected. However, It could be that 1 should not be selected. It could be that it is adjacent to another coin that is selected: coin 2 or coin 6. If we now do the above algorithm once for coin 2 instead of coin 1 and once for coin 6 we should have the best solution.

This approach relies on the fact that either coin 1, 2 or 6 is selected.

I hope I made my approach comprehensible. It's rather long and you could do it fasterr by using some state transition diagram in which you only maintain the possible states (which depends on the last 2 coins) and work on that. The methods are the same as above, only more compact)

Comment: Thankyou very much @origin , i will definatly try this , i think this should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Having everything in a circle hampers dynamic programming, because there is no stable start point.

If you knew that a particular coin would be included in the best answer, you could use that as your start point. Renumber it coin 1 and use dynamic programming to work out the best cost of 1..N, with and without the Nth coin selected. Given this you can work out the best cost of 1..N+1 and so on.

Actually you can also use this method if somebody tells you that a particular coin would *not* be selected - you just have slightly different starting conditions. Or you could use that fact that if you know that a particular coin is not selected, the two on either side of it must be selected.

Any coin is either selected or not, so you can look at the costs both ways, produced by solving two dynamic programming problems, and pick whichever cost is cheapest.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) suggestion, by induction. Hmm, I read the wiki now and I found out it counts as dynamic programming. Really a broad term. I had a different understanding of dynamic programming before.

**Glossary**

We have `N` coins in `N` places. Coin values are `a[i]`, where `0 <= i < N`. Each coin may be selected or deselected which we express as the sequence of `0` and `1`.

**Algorithm description**

`00` is invalid sequence in any place, because it would violate the problem constraints. `111` is also invalid because it is not optimal, `101` is always better.

Sequentially for every place `i` we calculate 3 best sums, for 3 codes: `01`, `10`, `11`. The code comes from the setting of last 2 coins, that is `i-1` and `i`. So we have best (minimum) sums in variables `b01`, `b02`, `b11`.

We have to start from something sure, so we will apply the algorithm 2 times. One for coin at place 0 set, and one for unset.

At the beginning we try places `0` and `1` and initiate `b`s directly. `b01 = a[1]`, `b10 = a[0]`, `b11 = a[0] + a[1]`. However if this is the round in which we choose the first coin to be unset, we can accept only `b01` solution. So we assign a big number to `b10` and `b11`. These solutions will be quickly dropped by next algorithm steps. On the second round we will do the opposite: assign big nuber to `b01`, because first bit must be set.

At step `i` we have best sums for place `i-1` in `b`s. We compute `c`s which are the best sums for place `i`.

```
c01 = b10 + a[i]    // 101 (10 -> 01)
c10 = min(b01, b11) // 010 (01 -> 10) or 110 (11 -> 10)
c11 = b01 + a[i]    // 011 (01 -> 11)
```

That comes from following possibilities:

```
010 - b01 -> c10
011 - b01 -> c11
100 - invalid
101 - b10 -> c01
110 - b11 -> c10
111 - invalid
```

Of course we finish each step with assigning best sums back to `b`s.

When we processed all the coins we must drop the solutions that are incompatible with the initial assumption. Bits `i-2`, `i-1` and `0` must produce valid sequences.

**This is example run for `123456` sequence.**

A. assume first bit `0`

```
1 a[1] = 2: b01 = 2, b10 = 999, b11 = 999
2 a[2] = 3: b01 = 1002, b10 = 2, b11 = 5
3 a[3] = 4: b01 = 6, b10 = 9, b11 = 1006
4 a[4] = 5: b01 = 13, b10 = 6, b11 = 11
5 a[5] = 6: b01 = 12, b10 = 13, b11 = 19
```

`b10` is unacceptable, we choose better from `b01` and `b11`, which is 12.

B. assume first bit `1`

```
1 a[1] = 2: b01 = 999, b10 = 1, b11 = 3
2 a[2] = 3: b01 = 4, b10 = 3, b11 = 1002
3 a[3] = 4: b01 = 7, b10 = 4, b11 = 8
4 a[4] = 5: b01 = 9, b10 = 12, b11 = 12
5 a[5] = 6: b01 = 18, b10 = 9, b11 = 15
```

Now `b11` is invalid as it would produce `111`. So we choose best of `b01` and `b10`, which is 9. Step A gave 12, step B gave 9. 9 is better. This is the result.

I made the above calculations manually, so sorry if there is a mistake in them. However for the first coin unset I computed 2+4+6 and for first coin set the result was 1+3+5. Seems to be right.